# How to Encapsulate Code in Main Method Using Java

Tags: java, encapsulation

How can I turn this code to encapsulation?
They said encapsulation is data hiding. I know how to do some overloading
and overriding,
but not encapsulation.

Please help me solve my problem.
I'm not that good in Java Programming.

Thank you in advance!

```
public class ATM {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       
       int bal = 1000;
       int balance =+ bal;
       
        System.out.println("===ATM Simulator===");
        System.out.println("\n[B] Balance");
        System.out.println("[W] Withdraw");
        System.out.println("[D] Deposit");
        System.out.println("[E] Exit");
        do{
        System.out.println("\nChoose Your Transaction:");
        String trans = input.next();
        try {
        if(trans.equalsIgnoreCase("W"))
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the Amount to Withdraw: [1000,500,200,100]");
            int wdraw = input.nextInt();
            int withd = wdraw;
            int charge = 10;
            if (withd%100==0)
            {
                balance = balance - withd - charge;
                System.out.println("Your current balance is now: "+balance);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Value Not in Range!");
            }
        }
        if(trans.equalsIgnoreCase("D"))
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the Amount to Deposit:");
            int deposit = input.nextInt();
            balance = balance + deposit;
            System.out.println("Your current balance is now: "+balance);
        }
        if(trans.equalsIgnoreCase("B"))
        {
            System.out.println("Your Current Balance is: "+balance);
        }
        
        if(trans.equalsIgnoreCase("E"))
        {
            System.out.println("Transaction Ended!\nThank you!");
            System.exit(0);
        }
            }
        catch (Exception e)
         {
             System.out.println("Invalid Input!");       
         }
        }
        while (balance>=200); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Just read, what encapsulation is: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encapsulation is the approach of "hiding" the fields of a class so that they are only accessible through methods of the class (thus controlling what the fields can and cannot be set to)

See - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_encapsulation.htm

EG: if a class has a `size` field, you would make the size field private and then provide a `setSize` methods on the class - you can then add validation within the `setSize` method to control what the size can and cannot be set to

Answer (score 0):

```
class employee
{
    private int id;
    private String name;

public int Getid()
{
    return id;
}
public void Setid(int n)
{
    this.id=n;
}
public String Getname()
{
    return name;
}
public void Setname(String h)
{
    this.name=h;
}

}

public class Encapsulation {
public static void main(String[]args)
{
    employee obj=new employee();
    obj.Setid(34);
    obj.Setname("amritpal");;
System.out.println(obj.Getid());
System.out.println(obj.Getname());
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.